# Services and battery consumption

Tags: android

I am working over a project that has many services that need to download and upload data from time to time. I was wondering, if we increase the number of services in an app, is this going to affect the battery consumption? Will it heavily drain or so?

Comment: Any process you add is going to require the use of the processor which will end up draining more battery. You just have to decide if your functionality is really necessary and if there's no other way to solve your problem. In your case, network usage tends to be a very "battery-draining" activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said any process will set a higher load on the processor, consequently draining more battery. At this link you can see some of the features that drain more battery:

http://electronicdesign.com/ed-europe/what-drains-smart-phone-battery

If your app consumes that much battery I would advise you to program it accordingly. Try to lower the number of update calls, if possible.